# How to show Last Modified "Date"

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to show last modified date in my column view. Currently, I have show person name who last modified the document as below code:

```
@Name([CN];@Subset( $UpdatedBy; -1))
```

So now I want to show date of last modified for another column view. Is there any way to show date of last modified using formula? Any help I really appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Modified` as the formula for the last modified date.

Comment: Unfortunately its not quite the same as what is returned by the REST API (9) for the @modified value - which I think is to do with last accessed